# OutOfMemory JSON Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to obtain an JSON answer type but is to big and at 50 MB Android Studio throw new Exception OutOfMemory

```java
class MyClass extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
String result="";

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params){

HttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();
String URL="http://82.79.121.114:1001/api/search/category/3,1,1";

try{

HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);

httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + AccesToken);

HttpResponse httpResponse=httpClient.execute(httpGet);
//Log.e("EROARE!!!!!!","EROARE!!!!!");

HttpEntity httpEntity=httpResponse.getEntity();

InputStream is=httpEntity.getContent();

result=convert(is);

}catch (Exception e){

e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid){

Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,result,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

if(result.length() == 0 || result == null)
{
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,result.Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

if(result.length() == 0 || result == null)
{
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Nu merge!!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}

public String convert(InputStream is) throws IOException {
BufferedReader reader = null;
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
try {

reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"),8192);
int read;
char[] chars = new char[1024];
while ((read=reader.read(chars)) != -1)
buffer.append(chars, 0, read);

}
finally {
if (reader != null)
reader.close();
}
return buffer.toString();
}
```

Comment: what in the world makes 50mb JSONs

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON object is simply too large, as most of the devices do not have such big heap. If you own the server-side, you should change the response you send to the clients and make it few separate responses, handled in a sequence.

In addition, I recommend you to rethink why you send so much data at once. It will take a very long time to load even on an average internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

If indeed the OutOfMemory problem is related with the size of the data returned by your REST service then you are doing it wrong both on server and client side. A mobile application should care about users data traffic and also about their battery so instead of loading the entire JSON in one shot maybe you can split it in pages and load only the first page first. Once the user is interested in more (maybe you are using a ListView there to show those categories) then you load the next page and so on. Please see the Endless List Patter for Android Here: 
https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews